# Docker keeps saying "No space left on device" when there's space in device

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-volume

i have two volumes attached to my ec2 instance, one is /dev/sda1 which is root volume and it is 8 Gb while there's another volume /dev/sdb which is 500GB. I can see both volumes when i run `sudo fdisk -l`. I have a django server running in docker instance running on this ec2 instance and when i upload some data to server docker "I/O error, no space left on device". How can i fix this problem?

**EDIT**

Following is my docker-compose.yml

```
# Copyright (C) 2018-2020 Intel Corporation
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
#
version: "2.3"

services:
  cvat_db:
    container_name: cvat_db
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: cvat
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    volumes:
      - cvat_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  cvat_redis:
    container_name: cvat_redis
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - redis
    restart: always

  cvat:
    container_name: cvat
    image: cvat
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - cvat_redis
      - cvat_db
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy:
        https_proxy:
        no_proxy:
        socks_proxy:
        TF_ANNOTATION: "no"
        AUTO_SEGMENTATION: "no"
        USER: "django"
        DJANGO_CONFIGURATION: "production"
        TZ: "Etc/UTC"
        OPENVINO_TOOLKIT: "no"
    environment:
      DJANGO_MODWSGI_EXTRA_ARGS: ""
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: '*'
    volumes:
      - cvat_data:/home/django/data
      - cvat_keys:/home/django/keys
      - cvat_logs:/home/django/logs
      - cvat_models:/home/django/models

  cvat_ui:
    container_name: cvat_ui
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        http_proxy:
        https_proxy:
        no_proxy:
        socks_proxy:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.ui

    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ui
    depends_on:
      - cvat

  cvat_proxy:
    container_name: cvat_proxy
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - cvat
      - cvat_ui
    environment:
      CVAT_HOST: ""
      ALLOWED_HOSTS: "*"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./cvat_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./cvat_proxy/conf.d/cvat.conf.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/cvat.conf.template:ro
    command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$CVAT_HOST' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/cvat.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

volumes:
  cvat_db:
  cvat_data:
  cvat_keys:
  cvat_logs:
  cvat_models:
```

Comment: Where is sdb mounted?

Comment: what do you mean by upload some data to the server, how you are trying to accomplish that?

Comment: Is your container using any volumes? They may be limited in size regardless of host  "real" volume size

Comment: @PierreB. check ,y edit

Comment: @tkausl how can i check that?

Comment: @Daviid i have a react app too, so from my browser i send an api request to django with data

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities.  Check out this article and see if it helps: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-linux-no-space-left-on-device-error/

It says things like

> **Deleted File Reserved by Process**
>
> Occasionally, a file will be deleted, but a process is still using it.
> Linux won’t release the storage associated with the file while the
> process is still running. You just need to find the process and
> restart it.
>
> **Not Enough Inodes**
>
> There is a set of metadata on filesystems called “inodes.” Inodes
> track information about files. A lot of filesystems have a fixed
> amount of inodes, so it’s very possible to fill the max allocation of
> inodes without filling the filesystem itself. You can use df to check.
>
> sudo df -i /
>
> Compare the inodes used with the total inodes. If there’s no more
> available, unfortunately, you can’t get more. Delete some useless or
> out-of-date files to clear up inodes.
>
> **Bad Blocks**
>
> The last common problem is bad filesystem blocks. Filesystems get
> corrupt and hard drives die. Your operating system will most likely
> see those blocks as usable unless they’re otherwise marked. The best
> way to find and mark those blocks is by using fsck with the -cc flag.
> Remember that you can’t use fsck from the same filesystem that you’re
> testing.

You might also want to post the question in a Linux exchange like https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's not related to your machine, It's related to your contained volume size limit As you can limit those. Can you inspect you container using `docker container inspect <container-Id>` and check the volumes associated to it, you can also inspect each volume by it's Id using the `docker volume inspect <volume-Id>` command.

After some research I'm more confident that these might be the issue check this thread it's a bit related https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5151